# Django Forms - Can the initial value of one field be dependant on another?

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms

Example, for this form:

```
class CommentForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(initial='class')
    action = forms.ChoiceField(...)
```

Can I have the choices in the action field be different depending on what is in the name field?

Comment: Do you mean when creating the form or dynamically when the user types something into the name field?

Comment: lemonad, this would be at form creation time, depending what I'm feeding the form for initial.

Answer (score 3):

How about wrapping *initial* in a function or a lambda, so that the value of initial is deferred until form creation. Something like:

```
class CommentForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(initial=lambda : self.action) # or more complex logic
    action = forms.ChoiceField(...)
```

Comment: does this work, is initial callable passed self? if yes why it is not in argument list, if no where from self is coming?

Answer (score 0):

I do have noticed that this question is 13 years old but it's still a top result on Google and the only answer is wrong / was already wrong at that time.

Here's a way to update the initial value of a Django field depending on another in a form (this is what I was looking for):

```py
class CommentForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(initial="class")
    action = forms.ChoiceField(...)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["action"].initial = your_custom_function(...)
```

If you need to update a ChoiceField / to limits foreign keys choices (as in the above example):

```py
class CommentForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(initial="class")
    action = forms.ChoiceField(...)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["action"].queryset = get_your_queryset(...)
        # OR
        self.fields["action"] = forms.ChoiceField( choices=get_your_choices() )
```